# iTunes connect not showing apps

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore, app-store-connect, in-app-purchase

Once clicking on apps in the iTunes connect home page, the information page shows up.

[image: Itunes]

to

[image: 2]

Is this usual, if so, how do I enable in-app purchases

Comment: Same problem.. any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can not enable apps in the latest version of iTunes. All apps are now downloaded and managed from the iPad or iPhone.